# whereBetween with dates not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to make a search query based on ages in Laravel. However, when I try to query between two dates, I get no results back. My code looks like:

```
    $today = Carbon::today();
    $age_from = $today->subYears($request->age_from)->toDateString();
    $age_to = $today->subYears($request->age_to)->toDateString();

    $users->whereBetween('birthday', [$age_from, $age_to]);

    //Get matching users.   
    $users = $users->Paginate(self::paginate);
```

The query looks right when I review with mySql(), but for some reason, I do not get any results. Syntax error maybe? Wrong use of toDateString and comparison of MySQL's date?

EDIT:
The output of $age_from is:

```
Carbon @959558400 {#245 ▼
date: 2000-05-29 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
}
```

The output of $age_to is:

```
Carbon @-302745600 {#245 ▼
date: 1960-05-29 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
}
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but i think you don't need to do `toDateString`. laravel querybuilder accepts carbon dates

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($age_from)` and `var_dump($age_to)`?

Comment: Just tried to remove it, but I still don't get any results back.

Comment: @Djave, I have updated my question with output.

Comment: "The query looks right when I review with mySql()" I'm not sure I really understand what that means - but can we see that?

Comment: I mean the query string ^_^.

Comment: "select * from `users` where `birthday` between ? and ? and `users`.`deleted_at` is null"

Comment: The earlier date has to come first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are mutating the `$today` object twice. If you check, `$age_from` has the same value as `$age_to` after line 3.

You should instead write:

```
$today = Carbon::today();
$age_from = $today->copy()->subYears($request->age_from);
$age_to = $today->copy()->subYears($request->age_to);
```

or simply

```
$age_from = Carbon::today()->subYears($request->age_from);
$age_to = Carbon::today()->subYears($request->age_to);
```

Comment: I have updated my code with yours, but no results, sadly.

Comment: Then check that you actually get results from your query, `$users->whereBetween('birthday', [$age_from, $age_to]);`, I assume you are using the Query Builder, so it must be `$users->whereBetween('birthday', [$age_from, $age_to])->get();`

Comment: I have tried with and without toDateString(). When I remove the whole whereBetween-clause, I do get results. I don't understand why I don't get any with whereBetween().

Comment: Try to run `dd($users->whereBetween('birthday', [$age_from, $age_to])->get());` to have laravel die and output the results of this statement. On the same line as before.

Comment: And of course make sure to do the changes to Carbon I wrote in this post too :-)

Comment: Still empty collection. It works though, if I manually type in dates as string.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the `$age_from` and `$age_to` variables contain what you expect them to? Check just before you use them in the database query.

Comment: I have dd both of them, even tried with border values, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to all, but especially both @skovmand and @Jonas Staudenmeir for helping me out; I solved the issue by facilitating @skovmand's code, and more importantly (and stupidity from my side), the dates should be swapped, so instead of [$age_from, $age_to], it is [$age_to, $age_from], as $age_to obvious is the start date. But thanks, guys! ^_^

Comment: Ah. So it was two different things. Good to hear you fixed it.